# How to import nodejs modules in vanilla Javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, scripting, node-modules

how does one import nodejs modules in a vanilla Javascript file? In other words, how can I use my nodejs modules in a vanilla javascript file for frontend scripting?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These modules are packaged using a tool called npm. You can use module loaders or bundlers like [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) to use npm modules in the frontend.

This might help you

Comment: I will try this as an alternative solution if other options don't work, but seems liable.

Comment: this was the most simple solution, thank you for sharing

Answer (score 14):

You can include them via a CDN, like unpkg or cdnjs. It lets you easily load any file from any package using a URL like:
`unpkg.com/:package@:version/:file`

For example, to get d3 on your page, you could add a script tag like so:

`<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@5.5.0/dist/d3.min.js" />`

[More Info](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/unpkg-an-open-source-cdn-for-npm)

Comment: Interesting, how could I turn one of my modules into a cdn? Also I meant as in including it into the vanila javascript file to reference in front end

Comment: I found out how to make the nodejs file into a cdn, but I am not sure how to access it in the script tag. So do I substitute unpkg.com for my domain? and is the :file the nodejs file itself?

Comment: By just publishing any library to npm, unpkg will pick it up and let it be used.

Comment: @NoobGuy which package are you trying to use?

Comment: I used module-to-cdn https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-to-cdn so to clarify if I named the package "lol" and the version was 0.1, will my url to access it be... "https://unpkg.com/lol@0.1/dist/lol.min.js"

Comment: Why do you want to include `module-to-cdn` in your front-end? But yes that is almost right, it depends what file in your package you want to load. Each package probably has it's code in a different place, d3 just puts a usable bit of code in `/dist/d3.min.js`. For example, a package I wrote can be loaded with `https://unpkg.com/nested-accordion@1.2.4/dist/generateHtml.js`

Comment: I tried <script type="text/javascript" src="unpkg.com/CypherChain@0.1/Cypher-Network/src/blockchain/index.js"></script> where I named my package CypherChain and the version was 0.1 and the path from root would be Cypher-Network/src/blockchain/index.js and I still got an error. ```GET https://goldengates.club/Cypher-Network/src/authentication/unpkg.com/CypherChain@0.1/Cypher-Network/src/blockchain/index.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404```

Comment: Have you `npm publish`-ed it? https://www.npmjs.com/package/CypherChain is blank

Comment: how does one publish it, I thought I got a dependency to do that. I may just be confused on how to use the dependency. But I didn't run npm publish anything

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question, is this what you want: https://docs.npmjs.com/using-npm-packages-in-your-projects

Comment: no, I tried using a package to publish my cdn. I have never published a cdn to npm and I don't know how this is done.\

Comment: You have a cdn? You can't publish a cdn to pm. Do you mean publishing a package to npm, so that a can can then host it for you?

Comment: Hey Luke, after importing the module from unpkg how do you go about using the module?

Comment: @GilsonViana It depends on how the module is set up, some will assign local variables, and some will attach to `window.PackageName` to allow useage - consult the docs for your package for further info, or failing that then you can view the actual script in your browser to see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the CDN, you can create a path with Node.js to get what you want from "node_modules"

in node.js

```
app.get('/jquery', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'))
})
```

in html

```
<script src="/jquery"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I decided to use browserify.

Answer (score 1):

use browserify to build your nodejs code so that it gets read by front end.